# ¿Cómo hacer un progressBar C#?

Tags: c#, progressbar

Estoy intentando mostrar una barra de progreso en lo que se ejecutan varios procesos (toma como 15 segundos), pero la barra de progreso nunca termina. Lo estoy intentando con un loop:

```
ProgressSQL.Maximum = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     ProgressSQL.Value = i * ProgressSQL.Maximum / 10;
     if (i == 10)
     {
         lblProgreso.Text = "Terminado";
     }
     else
     {
         lblProgreso.Text = "Progreso";
     }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el problema, lo agregué con la modificación, sigue quedando ahí.

Comment: Cuando dices que _nunca termina_, a que te refieres?

Comment: No termina nunca porque nunca es 10, en el for debes poner i <= 10

Comment: la barra de progreso no llega a su tope

Comment: No es que no termine, si termina, pero no te llega a mostrar lblProgreso.Text = "Terminado", porque deberías igualar i = 9, a menos que en tu for pongas <= 10

Comment: @ChristianGtz, verifique mi respuesta, la he actualizado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basado en que tu comentario dices: *la barra de progreso no llega a su tope*. Creo que te enfrentas a un problema clásico de las animaciones Aero de Windows.

Este retraso ocurre cuando se incrementa una barra de progreso. Pero no sucede cuando se decrementa la barra de progreso .

Así que, básicamente, lo que quiere hacer es mover pasado el valor real que debe llegar, a continuación, disminuir al valor real.

Debe hacer algo como esto:

```
int valor = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
{
     valor = Convert.ToInt16((i / 10) * 100.00);
     //Para evitar la animación progresiva, necesitamos mover el
     //barra de progreso hacia atrás.
     if (valor == ProgressSQL.Maximum)
     {
         // Caso especial como valor no se puede establecer mayor que Máximo.
         ProgressSQL.Maximum = valor + 1; // Aumentar temporalmente máximo
         ProgressSQL.Value = valor + 1;  // Mover el valor
         ProgressSQL.Maximum = valor;   // Restablecer máximo
     }
     else
     {
         ProgressSQL.Value = valor + 1; // Mover el valor
     }
     ProgressSQL.Value = valor; //Mover al valor correcto
     lblProgreso.Text =  i == 10 ? "Terminado" : "Progreso";
}
```

Comment: estas suponiendo demasiado (por ejemplo que usa aero, y si es winforms?) el error es que su for se escapa antes.. simplemente eso...

Comment: @gbianchi Y si es el caso?, independientemente de que el OP tengo fallas en cuanto a `i < 10`, yo tomé en cuenta lo que planteo en la respuesta, porque me paso algo similar en una ocasión, pero  esperaré a que el OP regrese al sitio, si no es el caso, entonces mi respuesta ya no estará. No hay problema en quitarla.

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que arreglar el for y dejarlo asi, ya que nunca llega a 10

```
ProgressSQL.Maximum = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            ProgressSQL.Value = i * ProgressSQL.Maximum / 10;

            if (i == 10)
            {
                lblProgreso.Text = "Terminado";
            }
            else
            {
                lblProgreso.Text = "Progreso";
            }
        }
```

Comment: igual, ProgressSQL.Maximum / 10 es siempre igual a 1.. no tendria mucho sentido en este caso

Comment: 2*10/10 es 2 por ejemplo..

Comment: Me referia a que 10/10 siempre es igual a 1 y despues multiplicas ese 1 * i.. o sea.. es siempre i... 3*10/10 es 3, 4*10/10 es 4.. se entiende? no tiene sentido, OP lo escribio como porcentaje, pero sobre 10 no tiene ningun sentido

Comment: Es una barra con maximo 10, que va de a 1, cada 1 es un 10%. No se a  que te referis con que no tiene sentido, al 10 completa la carga de la barra

Comment: no tiene sentido hacer multiplicar i por ProgressSQL.Maximum y dividir todo por 10.. si ProgressSQL.Maximum es 10, entonces matematicamente, es siempre i... hace las cuentas ;) ProgressSQL.Value = i es exactamente lo mismo que tenes escrito ahi